# Trying to pass a variable from DatabaseSeeder to factory in Laravel 8; is there new syntax?

Tags: php, laravel, factory, seed

Trying to pass a variable from DatabaseSeeder to factory in Laravel 8; is there new syntax?
I need to loop thru my users with foreach. I see a bunch of examples of passing variable to a factory as an array like this

```
// DatabaseSeeder.php
foreach ($users as $user) {
$round = Round::factory()->create(['user' => $user,]);
}
```

and I've also seen this:

```
$round = Round::factory()->create($user);
```

Most of those examples are several years old, but one is Sep'19. But neither way is working for me. I get:

```
// Terminal: php artisan db:seed
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Undefined variable: user", …
```

My foreach loop is definitely producing valid $user (confirmed via dd($user)). My factory def looks like this:

```
// RoundFactory.php
return [
    'user_id' => $user,
    'other_field' => $this->faker-> …something,
    other fields …
]
```

So is there some other way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading [Link 1](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding) and [Link 2](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#writing-factories). You could create UserFactory and implement `definition` method, add `HasFactory` trait to a model and then run this (x-how many do you want):

```
User::factory()->times(x)->make();
```

That is just one option to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I considered creating the parent (`user`) from within the child (`round`) but in my actual code there are several other models that make it impossible. But I found my mistake: confusing overriding the field value in the factory definition with passing a value to a variable like from a controller to a view. The syntax seems the same, I thought it works the same way. I thought I was supposed to be replacing the `$user` variable in the factory def. My fix is `'user_id' => 'overridden'`  in the factory def to remind me that the $user variable doesn't work.